# I cannot seem to install Sqlite3

Tags: node.js, linux, sqlite, npm, manjaro

I am a new linux user, running Linux manjaro and I have install node and npm using -n. When i try installing other packages, e.g bcrypt they install properly, however, when installing `sqlite3` using `npm isntall sqlite3` i get this error:

```
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/nsieverywhere/nodetest/node_modules/sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/nsieverywhere/nodetest/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/home/nsieverywhere/nodetest/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=6 --node_napi_label=napi-v6' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.11.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@14.15.4 | linux | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/home/nsieverywhere/nodetest/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.1/napi-v6-linux-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 403 https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.1/napi-v6-linux-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.1/napi-v6-linux-x64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@5.0.1 and node@14.15.4 (node-v83 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 403 status code downloading tarball https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.1/napi-v6-linux-x64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.15.4 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.15.4 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.1 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/nsieverywhere/nodetest/node_modules/sqlite3/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/nsieverywhere/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.4/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/nsieverywhere/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.4',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/nsieverywhere/.cache/node-gyp/14.15.4/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/nsieverywhere/nodetest/node_modules/sqlite3',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.15.4 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:10:17)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:57:18
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at step (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:54:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:71:22
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at subStep (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:69:33)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:22
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.9.16-1-MANJARO
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/nsieverywhere/nodetest/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=/home/nsieverywhere/nodetest/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64" "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=6" "--node_napi_label=napi-v6"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/nsieverywhere/nodetest/node_modules/sqlite3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.4
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/nsieverywhere/nodetest/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/home/nsieverywhere/nodetest/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=6 --node_napi_label=napi-v6' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/nsieverywhere/nodetest/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.9.16-1-MANJARO
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/nsieverywhere/nodetest/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/nsieverywhere/nodetest/node_modules/sqlite3
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.4
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/nsieverywhere/.npm/_logs/2021-02-04T11_19_30_090Z-debug.log
```

please note:

1. sqlite3 is installed globally on my linux machine (I checked by using sqlite3 --version)
2. I have also tried using `npm install --build-from-source`

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node error messages can be pretty intimidating.  I think if you look closely you'll see the details you need:

```
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/home/nsieverywhere/nodetest/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.1/napi-v6-linux-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 403 https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.1/napi-v6-linux-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.1/napi-v6-linux-x64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@5.0.1 and node@14.15.4 (node-v83 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 403 status code downloading tarball https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.1/napi-v6-linux-x64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
```

Specifically "WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@5.0.1 and node@14.15.4".

Then it fails to download the source with http 403 response code, so it can't download the source.

You'll need to do a little research to find what pre-built binaries *are* available and either upgrade to that version of sqlite or that version of node.

OR

Find a URL for the source code that works and tell node to use that. Since it failed to download both source and binary, I would start with telling node to use a different source that mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so I later solved this problem by using `npm install sqlite3@5.0.0` to install sqlite3.

Nodejs version - 14.15.4

npm    version - 7.5.2